# Blog posts not showing while using the FOR loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following .js code but when i test the site, it only displays the wordings as seen in each  but no contents. What i want to achieve at the end is to be able to display 5 posts and also add a link at the bottom to display more mosts:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    url = 'http://hopexxx.com/category/daily-devotion/feed/';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(){
            alert('Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed');
        },
        success: function(data){
            var postlist = data.responseData.feed.entries;
            var html = '<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">';
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                html += '<li>';
                html += '<a href="#">';
                html += '<div class="entry">entry.title</div>';
                html += '<div class="entry">author</div>';
                html += '<div class="entry">publishedDate</div>';
                html += '<div class="entry">contentSnippet</div>';
                html += '</a>';
                html += '</li>';
            }
            html += '</ul>';
            $("#postlist").append(html);
            $("#postlist ul[data-role=listview]").listview();

        }});
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that your postlist is not null, and that each entry has properties 'title', 'author', 'publishedDate' and 'contentSnippet' try this:

```
var postlist = data.responseData.feed.entries;
var html = '<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">';
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    var entry = postlist[i];

    html += '<li>';
    html += '<a href="#">';
    html += '<div class="entry">' + entry.title + '</div>';
    html += '<div class="entry">' + entry.author + '</div>';
    html += '<div class="entry">' + entry.publishedDate + '</div>';
    html += '<div class="entry">' + entry.contentSnippet + '</div>';
    html += '</a>';
    html += '</li>';
}
    html += '</ul>';
    $("#postlist").append(html);
```

Comment: thanks rusmus that worked. Do I need to create another js to enable me load each posts content when clicked on without it showing other page content on the main website

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. You should probably create a new question and add the relevant html and js there.

Answer (score 0):

try a $.each loop on data.responseData.feed.entries, see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) for details